# If D and C are on opposite sides of AB then D and B are on same side of AC

Tags: geometry

If D and C are on opposite sides of AB then D and B are on same side of AC.

It looks simple, but I can't prove. How to prove it?

Comment: Hint: Consider why there exists a quadrilateral $ACBD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof without words:

```
A---C
|\ /|
| X |
|/ \|
D---B
```